# Ревью кода. Передача методом нескольких значений, разного типа

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Есть необходимость что бы метод возвращал несколько значений, при этом различных типов.

Я так понимаю, самое правильное решение в java данной задачи состоит в следующем:

1. создать  класс оболочку для для необходимых значений.
2. в методе создать экземпляр данного класса
3. заполнить его значениями
4. возвратить данный объект через return
5. и считывать нужные данные через доступ следующего типа

   ```
   boo = method(args...).getVAlue();
   ```

Я конечно, так и сделал как описал выше, все отлично, все работает. Но что то, я сомневаюсь в данном решении.

Сильно возрастает количество кода. Приложу пример.

**Вопрос собственно в чем? Правильно ли я сделал, как можно было или нужно было сделать лучше?**

прикладываю сам код:

(класс оболочка со значениями)

```
public class PcThinkAnswer {
    private int direction;
    private int mapIndex;
    private int turnIndexH;
    private int turnIndexV;
    private boolean isAttack;
    private boolean isDefense;

    public int getDirection() { return direction; }
    public void setDirection(int direction) { this.direction = direction; }

    public int getMapIndex() { return mapIndex;}
    public void setMapIndex(int mapIndex) {this.mapIndex = mapIndex; }

    public int getTurnIndexH() { return turnIndexH; }
    public void setTurnIndexH(int turnIndexH) { this.turnIndexH = turnIndexH; }

    public int getTurnIndexV() { return turnIndexV; }
    public void setTurnIndexV(int turnIndexV) { this.turnIndexV = turnIndexV; }

    public boolean getIsAttack() { return isAttack; }
    public void setIsAttack(boolean attack) { isAttack = attack; }

    public boolean getIsDefense() { return isDefense; }
    public void setIsDefense(boolean defense) { isDefense = defense; }

}
```

(использования возвращенных значений)

```
private void pcTurn(PcThinkAnswer think) {
    if (think.getDirection() == 0) {
        think.setMapIndex(convertVHtoIndex(think.getTurnIndexV(), think.getTurnIndexH()));
        pcSetSymbol(think.getMapIndex(), think.getTurnIndexH(), think.getTurnIndexV());
    } else {
        think.setMapIndex(convertVHtoIndex(think.getTurnIndexH(), think.getTurnIndexV()));
        pcSetSymbol(think.getMapIndex(), think.getTurnIndexV(), think.getTurnIndexH());
    }
}
```

(сам метод со всей логикой)

```
private PcThinkAnswer toThink(String symbol) {
    PcThinkAnswer thinkAnswer = new PcThinkAnswer(); // a object 

    boolean isDefense = false; // vars
    boolean isAttack = false;
    int turnIndexH = 0;
    int turnIndexV = 0;
    int mapIndex = 0;
    int direction = 0;
    int directionFactor = 1;

    // ... some code
    // ... 
    // ... 


    thinkAnswer.setIsAttack(isAttack); // write to object
    thinkAnswer.setIsDefense(isDefense);
    thinkAnswer.setMapIndex(mapIndex);
    thinkAnswer.setTurnIndexH(turnIndexH);
    thinkAnswer.setTurnIndexV(turnIndexV);
    thinkAnswer.setDirection(direction);

    return thinkAnswer;
}
```

Comment: Количество кода не слишком возросло, но добавилась масса геттеров и сеттеров. Что бы они не захламляли класс, посмотрите на библиотеку `lombok`. С ней `PcThinkAnswer` будет выглядеть как список полей и одна аннотация `@Data` у класса, а в случае, если ваш класс должен быть неизменяемым, можете заменить все сеттеры на создание объекта билдером. IDEA умеет преобразовывать конструктор с множеством параметров в билдер, что бы понять как оно выглядит.

Comment: @Maxim как билдер решит проблему возврата нескольких разнотипных значений?

Comment: @pavlofff билдер решит проблему изменяемости класса, которые вероятно предполагает быть иммунабл.

Comment: вообще классы не самое лучшее решение для хранения информации

Comment: @michael_best вообще POJO-объект одна из основ ООП

Comment: @michael_best почему же? как раз таки в других языках есть отдельные типы данных `object = key:value`  @pavlofff ну да!

Comment: @pavlofff для этого есть БД

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у объекта нет никакого поведения, а есть только данные, то инкапсуляция с приватными полями, геттерами и сеттерами не имеет смысла. Не важно как вы обратитесь к переменной `method(args...).getVAlue()` или `method(args...).VAlue`.
Поэтому вы можете значительно упростить класс оболочку:

```
public class PcThinkAnswer {
    public int direction;
    public int mapIndex;
    public int turnIndexH;
    public int turnIndexV;
    public boolean isAttack;
    public boolean isDefense;
}
```

а так же способ работы с ним

```
private void pcTurn(PcThinkAnswer think) {
    if (think.Direction == 0) think.MapIndex = convertVHtoIndex1(think) ;// разбейте метод на два, передавайте в этот метод сразу объект целиком, а не отдельные поля
    else think.MapIndex = convertVHtoIndex2(think);// разбейте метод на два, передавайте в этот метод сразу объект целиком, а не отдельные поля
    pcSetSymbol(think);// вынесите повторяющийся метод за условие, передавайте в этот метод сразу объект целиком
}
```

в самом методе с логикой сеттеры теперь нужно убрать

```
private PcThinkAnswer toThink(String symbol) {
PcThinkAnswer thinkAnswer = new PcThinkAnswer(); // a object 

boolean isDefense = false; // vars
boolean isAttack = false;
int turnIndexH = 0;
int turnIndexV = 0;
int mapIndex = 0;
int direction = 0;
int directionFactor = 1;

// ... some code
// ... 
// ... 


thinkAnswer.isAttack = isAttack; // write to object
thinkAnswer.isDefense = isDefense;
thinkAnswer.mapIndex = mapIndex;
thinkAnswer.turnIndexH = turnIndexH;
thinkAnswer.turnIndexV = turnIndexV;
thinkAnswer.direction = direction;

return thinkAnswer;
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ!  точно!, лучше передавать сразу объект в метод `private void pcTurn(PcThinkAnswer think) {}` и да, инкапсуляция при объекте значений не уместна

Comment: Изменяемые публичные поля? Так себе идея.

Comment: @Maxim В случае `DTO` нет абсолютно никакой разницы, обращаетесь ли к полю по имени или  с помощью метода. Все геттеры и сетеры становятся мусорным кодом, бесцельной попыткой следовать неким формальным правилам (а тут из даже нет, JLS не требует наличия сеттеров) и шаблону. Именно на понимание этой идеи рассчитан мой пост.

Comment: @Mark с доступом все понятно, но почему не final поля со способом инициализации, который проверит (заставит) установить значения всем полям никого не забыв?

Comment: Делать объект мутируемым или не мутируемым - решать разработчику. Если объект появляется раз и на всегда, передается далеко, используется в разное время в разных местах,то  сделать `final` - разумное решение. Но здесь мы  видим что в `convertVHtoIndex` часть информации сразу модифицируется. Заставить инициализировать все поля можно конструктором, но здесь в этом тоже нет необходимости.

Answer (score 3):

Для уменьшения количества кода можно посоветовать библиотеку project lombock.

С ее использованием ваш класс будет выглядеть так:

```
@Data
public class PcThinkAnswer {
    private int direction;
    private int mapIndex;
    private int turnIndexH;
    private int turnIndexV;
    private boolean isAttack;
    private boolean isDefense;
}
```

Нужно добавить библиотеку в класспас.

Для мавена это будет выглядеть так:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
    </dependency>
```

Так-же нужно будет установить плагин для вашей IDE.

В остальном же с вашим кодом нет никаких проблем.

Answer (score 3):

1. Если изменение значений полей неактуально, то делайте поля неизменяемыми, добавляя модификатор final. В том числе смотри lombok: RequiredArgsContructor
   Это важно, потому однажды пользователь класса может задать вопрос "почему изменяемые поля" или изменить их значение. Тогда у объекта становится неопределенное состояние
2. getIsDefense - неправильное название по конвенции наименований java. Правильно:

   public boolean isDefense() {
   return isDefense;
   }
3. Почему для хранения обороны и атаки отвечают 2 boolean поля. Это значит, что объект может быть в состоянии аттака и оборона одновременно? Не думаю. Правильно ввести enum с именем, например, State.
4. Старайтесь не использовать примитивные типы для хранения значений (boolean может быть исключением). Тип примитивов невозможно расширить или сузить. В том числе они имеют дефолтные значения, которые могут не соответствовать логике Вашего приложения

Comment: спасибо за ответ 2. "getIsDefense" - я догадывался, что это не правильно) 3. нет, все верно, есть два возможных состояния одновременно, и оборона и атака, при этом атака имеет больший вес чем защита. Такой вопрос, верно ли создавать перечисления всего лишь для двух значений? (трех) есть ли какие то правила?

Comment: @boneferz На кол-во элементов перечислении (enum) правил нет, два - самое то